# How to speed up boot time by tweaking services?

Tags: boot, 20.04, lightdm

I changed the login manager to lightdm and disabled startup apps too. I was wondering whether there existed a possible way of holding back all services from starting up until i login into ubuntu. This way, only the bare minimum services required to boot will be started and this will definitely increase boot time. I also removed plymouth to disable the splash screen. To add, i also reduced the grub time. But i am really curious to reduce the loading up services at boot time to see what happens. Is there any possible way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

To see boot time of all the services you can use the command:

**systemd-analyze blame**

This will give you the number of seconds every service needs and will be a good starting point.

To see it in a graphical way you can use:

**systemd-analyze plot > startup.svg**

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be useful to know what to do with the items shown in this output. Any examples how to defer some of them?